# list category posts - Ability to add anchor jumps to links

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Installed this great plugin. Reading through your documentation, I cannot seem to find an option to do the following:

The ability to add an anchor tag (url.com/post/#anchorname) to the category listing urls displayed. Say we have 20 links in a category and after each URL have the ability to add a jump anchor tag #. This will be the same anchor tag for all the links in that category (example #downloads or #faqs etc)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! This site is for independent development - not plugin support. You are likely looking for the support site for the specific plugin that you are using. :)